# regex date validation on p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

my calendar has readOnlyInput="false" , hence the user can enter wrong dates such as 13/13/2013.

is there a way to regexValidate my date in case the user prefers to type the date instead of using the datePicker popup ?

```
<p:calendar id="birthDate" size="22" locale="#{view.locale}"
                            maxdate="#{userCreationBean.maxDate}" navigator="true"
                            yearRange="c-100" readOnlyInput="false"
                            value="#{userCreationBean.user.birthDate}"
                            mindate="01/01/1900" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            style="left: 194px !important;"

                            >
                        </p:calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`<f:validateRegex>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateRegex.html) validator works on `String` input values only, not on `Date` input values and is therefore insuitable for the purpose you had in mind.

Rather use the [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) converter.

```
<p:calendar ...>
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

It's by default [non-lenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) and will thus throw a converter exception when an invalid date is entered. You can if necessary customize the converter message by `converterMessage` attribute on the input component.

Comment: Hi @BalusC but this pattern allows date in format of '12/12/2013123', because the year is a valid one.  But is there any thing which accepts only 4 numbers in year also.